# Suspend not working correctly on MacBook Pro 5,5

Tags: 13.10, suspend, hibernate, macbook-pro

I've tried some answers from other questions similar, but no success.

I have a MacBook Pro 5,5 with Ubuntu 13.10 freshly installed from DVD.

Almost everything works straight out of the box but one issue, which is quite annoying, is that suspend doesn't work.

The issue:

Close the lid and system suspends - great this is what I want.
Open lid and try and resume system, get beyond a black screen almost to the log-in screen. I get to a screen showing the same background as I would have on a log-in screen, but nothing more than background. No log-in options at all. It then stays like this.
I then have to force the system to shutdown and start from scratch.

Any suggestions - do you need more info?

I'm new to Ubuntu but want it to work - rather than have to go and buy Mac OS to run on this system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try making your swap bigger. I always do 2x my ram plus 1 gig. So if you have 4gigs of ram the swap would be 9gigs. Overkill yeah but it works.